# What is difference between System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow and Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

There are 2 different official TPL Dataflow nuget package. I am confused to choose which one i should to use.

As far as i understand System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow version is tiny bit newer than other and it seems System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow is targeted latest versions of .net.

Anyone can explain differences between of those ?

Comment: "... is tiny bit newer .." - I have no idea which one you should use, but Microsoft TPL Dataflow is  Last published 2014-12-10 , while System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow is Last published   2016-06-27.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` was first released as a component separate from the BCL as part of .net 4.5 - here is a [blog post announcing the release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/05/30/mef-and-tpl-dataflow-nuget-packages-for-net-framework-4-5-rc-nick/)

`System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` as a separate package was created as part of the dotnet core release.  This [archived release history on github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/Archived%20Change%20Lists/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.md) shows the point where 4.5.24 of `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` (the last version on nuget) became 4.5.25-beta-23019 of `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` (the first version on nuget).

And [this old release note](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/ab5314af29352e61aa31ad38fd5058f4738ab5d4/release-notes/Archived%20Change%20Lists/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow.md) explicitly announces the name change.

It appears that the initial version was only for DotNet5.0 (as it was known at the time) but they have since made it backwards compatible.

So, most likely, you want `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow`.